# TYPO3 htmlArea RTE - cannot select images in Chromium

Tags: image, typo3, chromium, rte

Since upgrading to TYPO3 7.6/rtehtmlarea 7.6.0 I have been unable to select images when using the Chromium browser. This is with Chromium v59 on Linux Mint.
It works fine with Firefox.
I have reproduced this using the latest TYPO3 v7 (7.6.21). However, I have also reproduced it on a v6.2 site - so I think my associating the problem with an upgrade to 7.6 was a mistake.
When I click on an image using Chrome I get the following in the console log:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1.
    at Selection.selectNode (http://localhost/typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/JavaScript/HTMLArea/DOM/Selection.js?bust=d56abf6f622092c31162857ab5937b1f679b5b45:250:20)
    at Iframe.onMouse (http://localhost/typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/JavaScript/HTMLArea/Editor/Iframe.js?bust=d56abf6f622092c31162857ab5937b1f679b5b45:604:37)
    at HTMLHtmlElement. (http://localhost/typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Resources/Public/JavaScript/HTMLArea/Editor/Iframe.js?bust=d56abf6f622092c31162857ab5937b1f679b5b45:536:36)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.dispatch (http://localhost/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:6466)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.r.handle (http://localhost/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:3241)

Graham

Comment: Can you reproduce it when using latest 7.6 release?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my question as the association with TYPO3 7.6 was wrong.

Comment: can you still try with a different browser too? never saw that issue to be honest

Comment: It works fine with Firefox (55.0.1 (64-bit))